# Bash don't save history to file but allow up arrow to cycle through history

Tags: bash, bash-history

I have an Ubuntu which is shared by other people using my account. I don't want the to see my history by running the `history` command.

Here is what I have tried:

```
export HISTIGNORE='*'
```

It removes history (now running `history` doesn't show my command history) but it also makes me unable to press arrow keys to go through history.

I am not expecting solutions like "use a seperate account". Thanks!

Comment: I would try `export HISTFILESIZE=0`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @chicks, the solution to my question is:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=0
```